# Merge sort logic mistake

Tags: java

**EDIT:**
The problem seems to be that merge returns the sorted list but mergeSort doesn't work with the sorted list.

I tried to write a simple merge sort in java but I have an issue with it. It doesn't sort the array of integers correctly. I must have made an logic mistake but I can't find it out. I have written selection and bubble sort before and they work like they should. I would be thankful for any help :) Here is my code:

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] array)
{
    if (array.length <= 1)
    {
        return array;
    }
    else
    {
        int[] linkeListe = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, array.length/2);
        int[] rechteListe = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, linkeListe.length, array.length);

        mergeSort(linkeListe);
        mergeSort(rechteListe);
        return merge(linkeListe, rechteListe);
    }
}

public static int[] merge(int[] linkeListe, int[] rechteListe)
{
    int[] sortedArray = new int[linkeListe.length + rechteListe.length];
    int addElementPosition = 0;

    while (linkeListe.length > 0 && rechteListe.length > 0)
    {
        if (linkeListe[0] <= rechteListe[0])
        {
            sortedArray[addElementPosition] = linkeListe[0];
            linkeListe = deleteFirstElement(linkeListe);
        }
        else
        {
            sortedArray[addElementPosition] = rechteListe[0];
            rechteListe = deleteFirstElement(rechteListe);
        }

        addElementPosition++;
    }

    while (linkeListe.length > 0)
    {
        sortedArray[addElementPosition] = linkeListe[0];
        addElementPosition++;
        linkeListe = deleteFirstElement(linkeListe);
    }

    while (rechteListe.length > 0)
    {
        sortedArray[addElementPosition] = rechteListe[0];
        addElementPosition++;
        rechteListe = deleteFirstElement(rechteListe);
    }

    return sortedArray;
}

public static int[] deleteFirstElement(int[] array)
{
    int[] newArray;

    if (array.length > 1)
    {
        newArray = new int[array.length - 1]; 
        newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length);
    }
    else
    {
        newArray = new int[0];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: [I downvoted because your problem description is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: @JoeC I edited the post

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Stack Overflow :) it would be helpful if you could provide more detail in your question. You've shown us your code, which is great, but your problem statement isn't quite clear, even after your edit. Namely: "merge returns the sorted list but mergeSort doesn't work with the sorted list" -> what does "doesn't work" mean? Is there output, or an error? What is an example of a (input, actual output, expected output) set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change this:

```
mergeSort(linkeListe);
mergeSort(rechteListe);
```

to this:

```
linkeListe = mergeSort(linkeListe);
rechteListe = mergeSort(rechteListe);
```

On a side note, deleting the first element of the array like you are doing with deleteFirstElement is a huge performance issue.

Comment: Thanks i knew it was a dumb mistake. I will change the deleteFirstElement anyway, thank you :)